# Regarding nested for loops

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an assignment to use nested for loops to print out indices of a two dimensional array of 5 rows and 3 columns, without using arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int row;
    int column;
    cout << "Counting with nested loops: indices of row, column" << endl << endl;
    for (row = 1; row <= 5; row++)
    {   
        for (column = 1; column <= 3; column++)
        {

        }
        cout << row << "," << column << "\t" << row << "," << column << "\t" << row << "," << column << "\t" << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code I have so far. My goal is to print

> 1,1 1,2 1,3
>
> 2,1 2,2 2,3

and so on. When I run the program it prints

> 1,4 1,4 1,4
>
> 2,4 2,4 2,4

So I have the rows part correct. Could anyone help me figure out what my error is?

Comment: What will you print without having an array?

Comment: So where is your data stored?

Comment: @AndreasWalter I believe the question makes it clear: "print out indices of a two dimensional array" - he has to print the indices, not the contents, of an array. One of the few times perhaps when someone has said what they actually meant. :)

Comment: @davmac Thanks, reading sometimes helps!

Answer (score 0):

you need to call print just once but inside the inner loop like this:

```
for (row = 1; row <= 5; row++){
    for (column = 1; column <= 3; column++){
        std::cout << row << "," << column << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That did not print it in the proper format. It printed a lot more numbers than I should have.

Comment: Edited to print what you want

Comment: I certainly appreciate the help. I do not really understand what I was missing still, do you have a moment for a brief explanation? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you have to write:

```
int main() {
    int row;
    int column;

    cout << "Counting with nested loops: indices of row, column" << endl << endl;

    for (row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
        for (column = 1; column <= 3; column++) {
            cout << row << "," << column << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "\n\n\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is because you have to print **inside** the secondo loop and not outside.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have answered the question, but I wanted to add some suggestions to give things to think about in the future.

First where you introduce the loop variables, e.g. `int row;` you have not initialised them, and only need them in the `for` loop so declare them there. 
They then won't be visible outside the `for` loop, which would have avoided the mistake of printing (via `cout`) once the loop had finished.

It is also worth considering the loop counters. It's conventional to start at 0. Furthermore the indices of an array will start at 0 and run up to n-1. So you should consider printing 0, 1, ... rather than 1, 2, ... if you ever intend to use this to iterate through an array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Counting with nested loops: indices of row, column" << endl << endl;
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) //<--- note start at 0 and stop BEFORE n
    {   
        for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) //<--- ditto
        {
            cout << row << "," << column << "\t";
        }
        //cout << row << "," << column << "\t" 
               << row << "," << column << "\t"
               << row << "," << column << "\t" << endl;
                 // Now compile error
                 //  And clearly was going to just give the same value 
                 //  for row and column over and over
        cout << '\n';//added to break each row in the output
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```